# Getting crash log from unreleased application

Tags: android

I making an app that soon will be available in Play store. Meanwhile I am sending my couliges an apk each time there is an update. Of course the app crashes sometimes. Is there some simple mechanism that they could send me their logs in case app crashes? Or can you suggest some other way I can monitor ther crash logs?

Comment: Check if this helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QFEGP1mr-Q&ab_channel=Firebase

Comment: Firebase Crashlytics will give you realtime information about crashes with the stack trace. The users won't have to do anything to send you the information, it happens automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### PlayStore internal test track

You can track crash logs by releasing your apk to Google play internal test track.
This is the workflow of the internal test track.

1. Add internal testers by their email
2. Upload apk file on the internal test track
3. After the apk is uploaded you can share the shareable link to all testers.
   [image]

The link will ask your testers to join the beta program before they can download the apk. If the app is crashed you will get the full error log in the Google play console with the device name, available memory, etc.
**However, the error log will not be available immediately**(Sometimes it takes 1-2 hours). If you are interested in seeing the error logs immediately you should add [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics) in your app and then release the apk to the internal test track.
You can monitor the error logs in the Firebase console in Realtime.

Answer (score 0):

if there is no analytics in your app and your app is not in beta testing phase, your colleagues may capture bug report with their phone.

For more information :- https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/bug-report